# Upload file form uri using retrofit android with kotlin

Tags: java, android, api, kotlin, retrofit

I am trying to upload a video using retrofit, but I can't generate the correct format
this is my postman request :

postman request: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDC6s.png

and this is the API endpoint call :

```
@POST("uploadVideo")
suspend fun uploadVideo(@Body body: UploadVideoRequest) : Response<DefaultResponse>
```

,Also this the "UploadVideoRequest" class :

```
data class UploadVideoRequest(
    @SerializedName("video")
    val video: RequestBody? = null
)
```

finally this is my call :

```
fun createPostWithVideo(fileName: String) {

    val file = File(fileName);
    val requestFile = RequestBody.create("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull(), file)
    val body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("video", requestFile.toString())


    viewModel.uploadVideoRequest = UploadVideoRequest(
        video = body.body,
    )
    viewModel.uploadVideo()

}
```

But I am still not able to send that request

Comment: Where is `filename` coming from? Your title mentions "uri", but there is no `Uri` in your code.

Comment: its from file , not uri

Answer (score 2):

The way you are trying to send the video is not correct. Please follow these steps to send a video using retrofit.
First, create a network interface like this.

```
@Multipart
@POST("uploadVideo")
suspend fun uploadVideo(@Part part: MultipartBody.Part) : Response<DefaultResponse>
```

Second, call function like this:

```
fun createMultipartBodyPart(file: File) {
    val requestBody = RequestBody.create("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull(), file)
    val body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("name", file.name, requestBody)

    service.uploadVideo(body)
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it working or not but now I got this response  : 

oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4 


My api call : 

       fun uploadVideo(body: MultipartBody.Part) {
           viewModelScope.launch {
            apiRepository.uploadVideo(body)
                .let {
                    Log.e("DATA" , "${it.body()}")
                }
        }
       }

Comment: I don't think this works because you're only using the file's name and not the file itslef.

Comment: the file is used to create requestBody. review again.
RequestBody.create("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull(), file)